# Keras: how to retrieve training history in Ipython console

Tags: python, keras

During my model training, there is a sudden power outage in my house. Then my computer is shut down. When I restart the computer. Everything is lost. I have spent four days training the model. So frustrating!!

Is there way to retrieve the training results that are displayed in Ipython console at each epochs? Otherwise, I have to rerun the program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Linux then use the interactive shell with the `history` command.

Your training results which displayed in Ipython console will be recorded in a sqlite db in:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
```

instantly.

For the detail you can try to run with `history?` to learn more.